# How to update One to One relationship tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I wonder how to completely update One to One relationship tables through JPA save() method.

I tried to use the JPA save() method children table for update some data to children and parent tables.

Then i was expect update two tables(children and parent).
But there were updated parent table and inserted children table.

```
// parent Entity
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String content;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Children children;
}

// children Entity
public class Children {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullabel = false)
    private String picture;
    @OneToOne
    private Parent parent;
}

// Parent Table
id | title | content
1  | "..."| "..."

// Children Table
id | picture  | parent_id
1  | "..."     | 1



// Service
childrenRepository.save(childrenEntity);


// Result 
Updated Parent Tables;
-----------------------
id | title     | content
1  | "updated!"| "updated!"



Inserted Children Tables;
-----------------------
id | picture      | parent_id
1  | "..."        | 1
2  | "inserted!"  | 1     <---- This is not my purpose.




// The below's my purpose it.

Updated Children Tables;
-----------------------
id | picture           | parent_id
1  | "updated!"        | 1
```

Comment: It's less about your model definitions and more about how do you actually modify your children objects. Please post the code that fetches your `childrenEntity` and the code that updates it.

Comment: share your table relationship(ie pk and fk)

Comment: Your mapping is crap. You have no field "children" in Children, yet you claim to have it via the mappedBy

Comment: I was update the content more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your annotation for `Children` looks incorrect.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "children", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Children children;
```

Should be:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Children children;
```

> If the relationship is bidirectional, the non-owning side must use the
>   mappedBy element of the OneToOne annotation to specify the
>   relationship field or property of the owning side

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html)

Comment: I have a question. @OneToOne Annotation it need set to children Entity?